# Generating function for partition n with no part occurring once, and no part occurring 3 times.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

I have the following question, I'm not sure how to do :

Let $a_n$ be the number of partitions of $n$ in which no part occurs exactly once and no part occurs exactly three times. For instance with $n = 19$ then $3^2 2^4 1^5$ is such a partition.

Consider generating function

$$A(t)=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n t^n\;.$$

prove that

$$A(t)=\prod_{k\ge 0}\frac{1-t^k+t^{2k}-t^{3k}+t^{4k}}{1-t^k}\;.$$

Comment: Have you **some** formula for the g.f.?

Comment: no this is all that is given

Comment: I'll try again. Have **you** obtained some formula for the g.f.?

Comment: I know the g.f. functions for parts occurring exactly once, and no part occurring 3 times (separately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generating function for the total number of partitions is $$P(x)=(1+x+x^2+\dots)(1+x^2+x^4+\dots)(1+x^3+x^6+\dots)\dots=\prod_{k\ge 0} \frac{1}{1-x^k}.$$

To illustrate why this is, consider the partition $3^22^41^5$ and multiply together the second term (under the convention that the zeroeth term is $1$) in the third bracket $(x^6)$, the fourth term in the second bracket $(x^8)$, and the fifth term of the first bracket $(x^5)$. This product is $x^{19}$. Can you now see why the $x^{19}$ coefficient of $P(x)$ is the number of partitions of $19$?

So you should by now have guessed that $$A(t)=(1+t^2+t^4+t^5+t^6+\dots)(1+t^4+t^8+t^{10}+\dots)(1+t^6+t^{12}+t^{15}+\dots)\dots.$$

This can be simplified to
\begin{align}
A(t)&=\left(\frac{1}{1-t}-(t+t^3)\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-t^2}-(t^2+t^6)\right)\left(\frac{1}{1-t^3}-(t^3+t^9)\right)\dots\\
&=\prod_{k\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{1-t^k} - (t^k+t^{3k})\right)\\
&=\prod_{k\geq 0}\frac{1-t^k+t^{2k}-t^{3k}+t^{4k}}{1-t^k}
\end{align}